# Is there a way to move the mouse pointer with the keyboard?

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, mouse

Sometimes my mouse will freeze randomly. The only solution is to reboot the machine entirely.

However sometimes I just don't feel like rebooting and I resort to Ctrl + F, 'word here', ESC and then press enter to navigate websites.

As a better solution, do you know if there is a way to move the mouse pointer with the keyboard? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to System ->Assistive Technologies; then Keyboard Accessibility, under "Mouse keys"
and then check Pointer can be controlled using the keypad. And try.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)